# Where should I place the rspec helper functions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, rspec-rails

In railstutorial book it's been said we should create a spec/support/utilities.rb file and place the helper functions there. But it doesn't seem to work in newer versions of rails or rspec and when I define a function in that file and call it from the specs file, I get an `undefined method` error. I have also required `rails_helper`and `spec_helper`.

Comment: Rails Tutorial 3rd Edition is now in draft, and it is accessible. Rspec and FactoryGirl have been dropped in favor of the default Rails stack. The book now uses MiniTest and fixtures, which I found refreshingly simpler and more enjoyable than Rspec. I highly recommend you take a look.

Comment: you have to require this `spec/support/utilities.rb` file when you load RSpec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to require the files you put in that folder. Like this:

```
# In your spec_helper.rb

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
```

Comment: I put it in rails_helper.rb, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Rails 7 using rspec.

line 23 of the rails_helper.rb file already includes this line by default:

```
  Dir[Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', '**', '*.rb')].sort.each { |f| require f }
```

So now all you need to do is to create a file under the `support` directory such as spec/support/authentication.rb and add your functions.

```
def login(user)
   ...
end
```